# Mimetypes.init() error when installing package with PIP

Tags: python, pip, mime-types

**EDIT: Problem solved by opening C:\Python27\Lib\mimetypes.py and adding the code downside to the try block :**

```
## Begin to line 245 :    
try:
    ctype = _winreg.EnumKey(mimedb, i)
except EnvironmentError:
    break
try:
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
except UnicodeEncodeError:
    pass

## Here, add the universal Exception missing.
except Exception:
    pass

else:
    yield ctype
```

I'm searching from 3 days ago but solving this problem is too hard for me. I don't understant where is the problem.

I have tryed to install my package by using GitHub, PowerShell 3, etc. All are not working. Except PIP wich seems to have a little bug...

When I try to install **tweepy** by using PIP, this error appends :

```
Microsoft Windows [version 6.2.9200]
(c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

C:\Users\user>pip install tweepy
Downloading/unpacking tweepy
  Downloading tweepy-2.3.0.tar.gz
Cleaning up...
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 278, in run

    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundl
e=self.bundle)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 1229, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 292, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.s
etup_py, self.name))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req.py", line 265, in setup_py
    import setuptools
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 12, in <modu
le>
    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\extension.py", line 7, in <modu
le>
    from setuptools.dist import _get_unpatched
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 16, in <module>
    from setuptools.depends import Require
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\depends.py", line 6, in <module
>
    from setuptools import compat
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\compat.py", line 19, in <module
>
    from SimpleHTTPServer import SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 27, in <module>
    class SimpleHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 208, in SimpleHTTPRequestHand
ler
    mimetypes.init() # try to read system mime.types
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 358, in init
    db.read_windows_registry()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 258, in read_windows_registry
    for subkeyname in enum_types(hkcr):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py", line 249, in enum_types
    ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 3: ordinal
not in range(128)

Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log
```

Can you explain me, please, how to repear this ?

Thanks in advance,
SkyzohKey.

Comment: What does `pip --version` print out, and what does `C:\Users\user\pip\pip.log` say?

Comment: `pip --version` does nothing it say that program was not found. And the log file is here : http://textup.fr/105784KS

Comment: How can `pip --version` do nothing when you call it to install (`C:\Users\user>pip install tweepy`)..

Comment: Cause pip isn't installed due to the error. :x

Comment: You are confused.  `pip` is what you're using to install `tweepy`. I can see `pip` is running since you're getting output when you're running `pip install tweepy` (this runs `pip` telling it to install the `tweepy` package).  What is the difference between how you ran `pip install tweepy` and how you're running `pip --version`?

Comment: I finaly fail my sentence xD. I'm using PIP 1.5.6 with Python 2.7, problem not solved anyway :x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a mimetype in the windows registry that is causing problems.  You can run the following script to figure out which one it is:

```
import _winreg


def find_funky_mimetype():
    default_encoding = sys.getdefaultencoding()
    with _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
                         r'MIME\Database\Content Type') as mimedb:
        i = 0
        while 1:
            try:
                ctype = _winreg.EnumKey(mimedb, i)
            except EnvironmentError:
                break
            print 'testing:', `ctype`,
            try:
                ctype = ctype.encode(default_encoding) # omit in 3.x!
            except UnicodeEncodeError:
                print 'expected failure'
            except Exception as e:
                print 'unexpected failure:', e
            else:
                print 'ok.'
            i += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    find_funky_mimetype()
```

What you should do about it is entirely up to you and what you feel comfortable with (e.g. removing the offending mimetype from the registry or adding a universal except in line 252 of `c:\Python27\lib\mimetypes.py similarly to what I've done above).

Comment: I doesn't have any sort of error while running your script, all the mimetypes are "ok". (ps: you forget to import sys ^^)

Answer (score 0):

change line 250

```
except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
    pass
```